# Automated tests for OpenLayers library (Cucumber, gherkin...)?

Tags: angular, automated-tests, cucumber, openlayers, gherkin

I am actually coding an app with OpenLayers (v7) and Angular framework.
I would like to automate some tests in order to check if everything is running as planned.

We use Cucumber (gherkin).

Does anyone has experienced building automated test with a similar tool for OpenLayers features ?
For instance, I am looking forward to test some "clicks" feature. If a click on an OpenLayers vector then it should change its styling etc...

I could not find any resources so far neither here or in the library's github page.

As far as I understand it might not be possible because Cucumber is easy to use with HTML elements and OpenLayers uses a canvas that could not be used with the tests.

I would appreciate any lead as small it could be.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: OpenLayers has tests which simulate events. e.g. https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/main/test/browser/spec/ol/interaction/select.test.js#L97-L113

Comment: Interesting ! Thanks.